# How to properly use JSON.parse in kotlinjs with enums?

Tags: json, parsing, kotlin, enums, kotlin-js

During my fresh adventures with kotlin-react I hit a hard stop when trying to parse some data from my backend which contains enum values.
Spring-Boot sends the object in JSON form like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "Johnny",
  "role": "CLIENT"
}
```

`role` in this case is the enum value and can have the two values `CLIENT` and `LECTURER`. If I were to parse this with a java library or let this be handled by Spring-Boot, `role` would be parsed to the corresponding enum value.

With kotlin-js' `JSON.parse`, that wouldn't work and I would have a simple string value in there.

After some testing, I came up with this snippet

```
val json = """{
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Johnny",
        "role": "CLIENT",
    }"""

val member: Member = JSON.parse(json) { key: String, value: Any? ->
    if (key == "role") Member.Role.valueOf(value.toString())
    else value
}
```

in which I manually have to define the conversion from the string value to the enum.

**Is there something I am missing that would simplify this behaviour?**

(I am not referring to using ids for the JSON and the looking those up, etc. I am curious about some method in Kotlin-JS)

I have the assumption there is not because the "original" `JSON.parse` in JS doesn't do this and Kotlin does not add any additional stuff in there but I still have hope!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, no.

## The problem

Kotlin.JS produces an incredibly weird type situation when deserializing using the embedded JSON class, which actually is a [mirror for JavaScript's JSON class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). While I haven't done much JavaScript, its type handling is near non-existent. Only manual throws can enforce it, so `JSON.parse` doesn't care if it returns a `SomeCustomObject` or a newly created object with the exact same fields.

As an example of that, if you have two different classes with the same field names (no inheritance), and have a function that accepts a variable, it doesn't care which of those (or a third for that matter) it receives as long as the variables it tries accessing on the class exists.

The type issues manifest themselves into Kotlin. Now wrapping it back to Kotlin, consider this code:

```
val json = """{
        "x": 1, "y": "yes", "z": {
            "x": 42, "y": 314159, "z": 444
        }
    }""".trimIndent()

data class SomeClass(val x: Int, val y: String, val z: Struct) 
data class Struct(val x: Int, val y: Int, val z: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val someInstance = JSON.parse<SomeClass>(json)
    if(someInstance.z::class != Struct::class) {
        println("Incompatible types: Required ${Struct::class}, found ${someInstance.z::class}");
    }
}
```

What would you expect this to print? The natural would be to expect a `Struct`. The type is also explicitly declared

Unfortunately, that is not the case. Instead, it prints:

```
Incompatible types: Required class Struct, found class Any
```

### The point

The embedded JSON de/serializer isn't good with types. You might be able to fix this by using a different serializing library, but I'll avoid turning this into a "use [this] library".

Essentially, `JSON.parse` fails to parse objects as expected. If you entirely remove the arguments and try a raw `JSON.parse(json);` on the JSON in your question, you'll get a `role` that is a `String` and not a `Role`, which you might expect. And with `JSON.parse` doing no type conversion what so ever, that means you have two options: using a library, or using your approach.

Your approach will unfortunately get complicated if you have nested objects, but with the types being changed, the only option you appear to have left is explicitly parsing the objects manually.

**TL;DR:** your approach is fine.